# TCP connection beteen linux server and android application

Tags: android, linux

I want to establish connection between android application with Linux based server(python code), for this I had created sockets one in android app and one in python(which is running on Linux platform). When I was running code, android app socket gets timed out, but unable to establish connection. Please help me to figure out this. Thanks in advance.
[Python code for server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niLhx.png)

Comment: what is your python code?

Comment: do you have internet permissions on Android? are you sure you are using the correct url/ip and port of the server?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have mentioned internet permission on android

Comment: @pskink I have attached python code

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I am sure about the ip and port of server I'm using

Answer (score 0):

Create an INET and STREAMing socket. Following example give you a clear idea about how to create INET and STREAMing socket.

Instead of this:

**s = socket.socket()**

Use this:

**s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)**